# Take user input as argument and output result of simple formula. Get error message 'not defined'

Tags: python

I am writing a simple program that takes user input as its arguments and runs these through a simple formula and then outputs the result. But I think something is wrong with my syntax and I don't understand what.

```
def P2(packets = input("Please enter nr of packets: "), switches = input("Please enter nr of switches: ")): 

    delay = 1
    time = (packets + (switches-1)) * delay

    #print("The time it takes to send " % packets % " packets back-to-back over " % switches % " switches is: " % time)
    print("The time it takes to send () packets back-to-back over () switches is: ()".format(packets, switches, time))

P2(packets, switches)
```

I get error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/amali/PycharmProjects/LearningPython/100PyEx1/P2Program.py", line 8, in <module>

    P2(packets, switches)

NameError: name 'packets' is not defined
```

Comment: Move your input statements outside of your function definitions, assign them to the variable, _then_ pass them into your functions

Comment: I tried moving the input statements, but then I get an error before the program asks for inputs. If I keep it like it is I at least get some output before the error occurs..

Comment: It would be completely wrong but you can just call the function without parameters like `P2()`. You should do as suggested and ask for user input outside the function

Answer (score 3):

You need to define packets and switches outside your function and the call the function with them:

```
def P2(packets, switches):
    delay = 1
    time = (packets + (switches-1)) * delay

    #print("The time it takes to send " % packets % " packets back-to-back over " % switches % " switches is: " % time)
    print("The time it takes to send %s packets back-to-back over %s switches is: %s" %(packets, switches, time))

p = input("Please enter nr of packets: ")
s = input("Please enter nr of switches: ")
P2(p, s)
```

Edit:

If you don't need the actual variables, you can do:

```
P2(input("Please enter nr of packets: "), input("Please enter nr of switches: "))
```

I think that's less readable, but it works...